# How to choose between objects in Python

Tags: python, object

I know it is a good practice not to give different objects the same name, but for the sake of curiosity, is it possible to choose a specific object out of multiple objects of the same name?

```
>>> exampleobject=0
>>> def exampleobject():
...     print('This is a function.')
>>> class exampleobject:
...     def exampleobject():
...         print('Hello World!')
>>> type(exampleobject)
    <class 'type'>
```

And so on. As you can see, the type of the object depends on which order you define them in. Is there an explanation for this?

Furthermore, once you define a function in place of a variable of the same name, does the variable get deleted?

P.S. I know this question sounds stupid.

Comment: Garbage collector will collect the previous data, as there are no other references to that data.

Comment: Please do not name your variables the same thing as builtins. (`object` is a builtin)

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it depend on the order you define them? If you call something "foo" and then call something else "foo", why wouldn't you expect "foo" to refer to the last thing you used the name for?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, but does the first one get deleted or something?

Comment: @JAW As somebody has noted in the answers, you only have 1 variable and you assign different values to that same variable every time so the is no first or last ones. As for the data, yes, it gets collected by the garbage collector.

Comment: @k So you're saying the data gets overwritten or otherwise swept away.

Comment: Python memory management (at least in CPython) is done by reference counting. When the number of references to an object goes to 0, it is deleted.

Comment: @JAW Your variable is just a reference to some object. When you reassign, you give some other reference to some other object. The first object gets deleted, as there is no way to access that object any more(you changed the value of its only reference.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is dynamic language, so you could assign values of different types (int, string, function) to the same variable:

```
>>> o=1
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'o': 1, '__package__': None}
>>> type(o)
<type 'int'>
>>> def o():
...     print 1
... 
>>> type(o)
<type 'function'>
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'o': <function o at 0x7fba38e21578>, '__package__': None}
```

Comment: I see. However, did the first variable `o` get deleted?

Comment: it is not deleted, it is assigned with different value, function instead of int

Comment: Actually o is reference variable, So, it'll not be deleted, actually the object to whom it was pointing may be deleted(garbage/collected), provided that o is now pointing to something else and there're no other reference variables, which are holding reference to that variable.

Comment: we talking about variable itself, not value. variable was not deleted, it was reassigned, old value will be garbage collected, but it is a different story.

Comment: I don't really see how the question has anything to do with dynamic typing.

Comment: question was edited and not everything was changed properly during edit, I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have given object is not the actual object, but just a reference to object. In python, everything is object.

For more clarity, I'll use myObj.
So,

```
myObj=2
```

will make myObj to point to integer object.

```
class myObj:
  pass
```

will create a new type object, and assign its reference to reference variable myObj. Thus reassignment of handles of different objects to same reference variable, determine the type of reference variable. In other words, type(myObj) will give you the type of object, whom myObj is pointing to.

For more info. refer to python docs.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the output `globals()`. The value you defined in current file will be stored there. So if you define two objects with the same name, the first one will be overrided by the second one. Also you can try `globals['A']=1`, which is equal to `A=1`